# Proper use of stop and delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I have some issues with my js code. I want to animate a simple click function so that a div, shows the div below but animates back after say 5 seconds. I think I got the right setup with fadeToggle and delay but I just don't get it how to set up "over-clicking" prevention. I mean when people mess with the click-object.

My first attempt was `stop(true,true)`. Although it seems that it works as expected (aborting further function execution) it unfortunately shows the underlying div after 5 seconds although it should show the upper one (picture).

Here is the js and the fiddle:

```
$(function() {
  $("#boxes li").on("click", function(){    
    $(this).find(".front,.back").stop(true, true).fadeToggle(800).delay(5000).fadeToggle(800); 
  });
});
```

but also a js fiddle link to see what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/sfiddle/bqbPL/

Regards,

PS: try first to click once to see what effect I want to accomplish and then click 2 times to see how after 5 seconds it will show the text div.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified it a bit,

but still require some work on it, you may use some flag variable with click,

Please see the updated ['fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/bqbPL/1/), it handles the process but stores the next click that occurs after it fade back.

Update: to avoid double clicking

Creating a flag is, you will create a Boolean variable, that will be true/false. (or int variable with 0 or 1),

Like:

`var flg=true;`

Now, this variable called flag, flag is initiated with False/True value(as per requirement) then we will modify flag after the event occur(the event we want to watch out, here click of button) once event occurs we will change the flag.

In the second you will add flag to condition. `if( condition == true && flag == true) {....}` so, if flag is changed to false after event/click the event in if will not occur again.

I hope this will help..

Comment: Thanks @MarmiK, but this does not work as I intend to. You can mess this up quite easyly by clicking twice after another. Other suggestions?

Comment: You need to create flag, that will change after each click, and change again after it is normal.

Comment: OK thanks so far. I'll check that out later. Maybe I should have mentioned that I am a beginner with js and flag does not tell me anything right now.

Comment: Hey @MarmiK, I just dont get what you mean by creating a flag. Can you provide me with a hint?